# 550 relay is not permitted on this host

Tags: networking, email, postfix, smtp, sles

I'm Working on multiple sever (9 Linux Suse 11 and Linux Suse 12) 7/9 (email working) (all under the same network) are able to send email like script below,
I need to send email from shell script to an external domain.

```
mailx  -a /opt/script/log/status.log  -S smtp=[..].net -r 
"test@gmail.com" -s "$HOSTNAME critical_subject " -v "mymail@gmail.com" << EOF
Critical Status found during the Monitoring and Control Operation. Please 
check the Attach Log.
EOF
```

as result i got this :

```
  Resolving host [..] . . . done.
Connecting to [..]:smtp . . . connected.
220 [..] ESMTP Wed, 02 Aug 2017 09:42:58 +0200
>>> HELO a.b.c
250 a.b.c.Hello [..]
>>> MAIL FROM:<test@gmail.com>
250 OK
>>> RCPT TO:<mymail@gmail.com>
550 relay is not permitted on this host.
smtp-server: 550 relay is not permitted on this host.
"/root/dead.letter" 102/5133
. . . message not sent.
```

any suggestion? which info can i provide?

main.cf

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

mail_owner = postfix


# REJECTING MAIL FOR UNKNOWN LOCAL USERS
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP


debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq

setgid_group = maildrop

html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/html
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/README_FILES

biff = no
content_filter = 
delay_warning_time = 1h
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = 
masquerade_exceptions = root
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
myhostname = domain.domain.net
mynetworks_style = subnet
mynetworks= [list of ip in subnet form]
relayhost = relay_adress

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
message_strip_characters = \0
defer_transports = 
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_transport = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = no

smtpd_client_restrictions = 

smtpd_helo_restrictions = 

smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination


############################################################
# SASL stuff
############################################################
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_security_options = 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
############################################################
# TLS stuff
############################################################
relay_clientcerts = 

smtp_use_tls = no
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_tls_CAfile = 
smtp_tls_CApath = 
smtp_tls_cert_file = 
smtp_tls_key_file = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = 

smtpd_use_tls = no
smtpd_tls_CAfile = 
smtpd_tls_CApath = 
smtpd_tls_cert_file = 
smtpd_tls_key_file = 
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_received_header = no

############################################################
# Start MySQL from postfixwiki.org
############################################################
relay_domains = $mydestination, hash:/etc/postfix/relay
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**UPDATE**: For some reason I cannot send email from that host. So I'm triyng to use 
 one of the 7 working machine in order to send the email. Added on the "broken" one mynetworks list of ip, and realy_host as the adress of the working that i want to use as relay. 
In the relay one, i added in mynetworks the adress of the broken one. 
Did not work

**UPDATE2**: It was an SMTP problem by the customer client. I'll Close the question.

Comment: Do you mean 7 out of 9 are working? Either way this is a simple relay issue. Your clients either need to authenticate with the server (if possible), or the server needs to be configured to allow relaying for the IP addresses your clients are using

Comment: Yes 7/9 email working, /etc/postfix/main.cf is the same for all of them.
I need to send email from shell script to an external domain. 
So possible i can't auth with the smtp,

Comment: Please add the `main.cf` of the SMTP server giving this error.

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this error comes after `RCPT TO:`, the corresponding Postfix configuration parameter is either [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) or [`smtpd_relay_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions), depending on this:

> With Postfix versions before 2.10, the rules for relay permission and
>   spam blocking were combined under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`,
>   resulting in error-prone configuration. As of Postfix 2.10, relay
>   permission rules are preferably implemented with
>   `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, so that a permissive spam blocking policy
>   under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` will no longer result in a
>   permissive mail relay policy.

Your have

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

and as non-present, your `smtpd_relay_restrictions` falls into default:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
```

Since your script is not authenticating with SASL, it should be permitted by `permit_mynetworks`, i.e. it must be listed in [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks). You haven't specified it in your configuration, but you can check it with `postconf | grep "mynetworks = "`. As you are connecting to external interface instead of localhost (`smtp=[..].net`), it should include the external IP.

**This may affect the default value of [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks), causing differences between your servers:**

> Specify `mynetworks_style = subnet` when Postfix should "trust" remote
>   SMTP clients in the same IP subnetworks as the local machine. On
>   Linux, this works correctly only with interfaces specified with the
>   `ifconfig` command.

Therefore, it may be better to specify the [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) parameter manually, e.g.

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 198.51.100.10/32
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
So i should remove the reject_unauth_destination from smtpd_recipient_restrictions.
Then postconf result : 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128

so in mynetworks_style = what should i insert?

Comment: You only need to add the public IP of your server to `mynetworks` list.

Comment: i Add this: 
mynetworks_style = subnet
mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8, public_ip_adress but got the same error

Comment: Yes, but in a subnet format i.e. add `/32` for a single IP, e.g. `198.51.100.10/32`. I also added this as an example to my answer.

Comment: Mask:255.255.240.0
use that for public ip : curl ipinfo.io/ip
mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 publicip/20 
same error, what im doing wrong?

Comment: also performed postfix reload

Comment: See if there's anything related in `mail.log`. It should also show the IP your script is using for connecting the SMTP server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63210/discussion-between-danieleo-and-esa-jokinen).

Comment: It was SMTP Customer side problem. I Will accept your answer because of your great suggestion and help.

Comment: Just because the error comes after the `RCPT TO` command doesn't necessarily mean that the problem is with the relay or recipient restrictions, with modern versions of Postfix. See [Delayed evaluation of SMTP access restriction lists](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing). That's controlled by the [`smtpd_delay_reject`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_delay_reject) setting (which the OP has explicitly specified as its default value `yes`).

Comment: Thanks Michael, didn't notice `smtpd_delay_reject = yes`! However, the addition to `mynetworks` should have still helped in this situation.